# How to achieve following column reordering with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css

In a mobile first design I have 3 columns stacked as illustrated below

```
A
C
B
```

for >= md viewports I want to achieve the following layout

```
AB
C
```

can this be readily done with Bootstrap? I have troubles with pull/push columns

Comment: What troubles do you have with push/pull columns?  What have you tried?

Comment: I was able to get that aligned like ABC vertically but could not get the A and B aligned side-by-side

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Try out this really slick explanation / tutorial for more information:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Simpler to do this order instead:

```
A
B
C
```

and for md

```
AC
B
```

And assign these classes:

1. A = col-md-6
2. B = col-xs-12 col-md-push-6
3. C = col-md-6 col-md-pull-6

Comment: this is not exactly what I was looking for - nevertheless good reading